# How to remove an element after equally compared?

Tags: java

I am currently working on my homework which is to make an alarm simulation, one of my methods is to remove the alarm after being compared to `getTime` and also be able to remove the alarm without being compared to.
I consider the issue with the x index in the `alarm.remove(alarm.get(x).equals(getTime()));`

What should I put there instead of x?

```
public class AlarmClock extends Clock {

    private ArrayList<String> alarm;

    public AlarmClock() throws IllegalValueException {
        super();
        alarm = new ArrayList<String>();

    }

    public AlarmClock(int hour, int minute) throws IllegalValueException {
        super(hour, minute);
        alarm = new ArrayList<String>();
    }

    public void removeAlarm() {
        for (int x = 0; x < alarm.size(); x++) {
            if (alarm.get(x).equals(getTime())) {
                alarm.remove(alarm.get(x).equals(getTime()));
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Hi ! Does `getTime()` return a String value ?

Comment: Don't iterate this way! Iterate with forEach or use the Java Stream API.

Comment: @baitmbarek yes my getTime returns String value

Comment: Can you add geTime() implementation? I think you are comparing different types.

Answer (score 0):

You just want the index:

```
alarm.remove(x);
```

However, that will change the `List` length.

The hack way to do it is to iterate backwards.

```
// Don't do this.
public void removeAlarm() {
    String time = getTime();
    for (int x = alarm.size(); --x >= 0; ) {
        if (alarm.get(x).equals(time)) {
            alarm.remove(x);
        }
    }
}
```

Better is to use `Iterator`.

```
public void removeAlarm() {
    String time = getTime();
    for (Iterator<String> iter = alarm.iterator(); iter.hasNext(); ) {
        String a = iter.next();
        if (a.equals(time)) {
            iter.remove();
        }
    }
}
```

Or much, much better, use `removeIf`.

```
public void removeAlarm() {
    String time = getTime();
    alarm.removeIf(a -> a.equals(time);
}
```

I'm assuming your call to `equals` is correct.

Answer (score 0):

@Asaranow You need to change the following because right now you are passing in a boolean to the remove method which should get a int passed in.

```
public void removeAlarm() {
    ArrayList<Integer> toRemove = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int x = 0; x < alarm.size(); x++) {
        if (alarm.get(x).equals(getTime())) {
            toRemove.add(x);
        }
    }
    for (int indexToRemove : toRemove) {
        alarm.remove(indexToRemove);
    }
}
```

Comment: never change a loop variable inside of the loop!  Have you tried your code? i guess you get a concurrent modification execpetion

Answer (score 0):

```
String a = alarm.get(x)    
if (a.equals(getTime())) {
  alarm.remove(a);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please edit your answer and add some description about the code. Code only answers are discouraged.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove it like this:

```
    public void removeAlarm() {
        for (Iterator<String> it = alarm.iterator; it.hasNext();) {
            String str = it.next();
            if (str.equals(getTime())) {
                it.remove();
            }
        }
    }
```

If you don't use an iterator to do the remove you can end up with an out of sync list relative to what you just removed.  That would result in a `ConcurrentModificationException`